# Playwright beforeAll *after* a fixture

Tags: playwright

I have a `login` fixture that I want to run at the beginning of every test in the repository. I then want to do a `beforeAll` and `afterAll` script (supply and then delete data) to run before/after a group of tests in a `describe` block. However, the `beforeAll` runs before the `login` fixture.

Am I approaching this from the wrong angle?

Comment: Please share the code what you tried so far in the form of minimal reproducible example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This isn't a question for "why does my code not work" but "what are patterns for achieving 'x'". An example would not provide any extra information to help people find or help answer this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a login fixture that I want to run at the beginning of every test in the repository. However, the beforeAll runs before the login fixture.

Check globalSetup and Auth

- https://playwright.dev/docs/test-global-setup-teardown
- https://playwright.dev/docs/auth

Comment: Auth is exactly what I wanted, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your project needs, you could add your data by using setup and teardown [project dependencies](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-global-setup-teardown) in your playwright.config.ts.

So your config could include something like this - my chromium project has a dependency on 'setup'.  So 'setup' will be run first and has tests to setup my data, then 'chromium' tests run, and then 'teardown' tests to nuke your data.

```
projects: [
    {
      name: 'setup',
      testDir: 'tests/setup/',
      teardown: 'teardown',
    },
    {
      name: 'teardown',
      testMatch: /tests/teardown/,
    },
    {
      name: 'chromium',
      dependencies: ['setup'],
      use: {
        browserName: 'chromium',
        headless: false,
        screenshot: 'only-on-failure',
        trace: 'on',
        launchOptions: {
          args: ['--disable-extensions '],
        },
      },
    },
  ],
```